# Empty pdf with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, snakemake

I have I am trying to save a pdf with path being called via snakemake. I am using vec to loop through each gene in feature plot. I want to make one plot per page and have a list of pages in each pdf that I can look at. However, I keep getting an empty pdf output with zero pages. I am not seeing what is wrong.

```
pdf(file = snakemake@output[['GeneLabel']], onefile=FALSE)
vec<- c("DKC1", "NOP10", "WRAP53", "POT1", "PARN")
for(i in vec){
  FeaturePlot(cts.seurat.obj, features = c(i))
}
dev.off()
graphics.off()
```

Comment: Having some way to reproduce the problem is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about it, but try this:

```
pdf(file = snakemake@output[['GeneLabel']], onefile=FALSE)
vec<- c("DKC1", "NOP10", "WRAP53", "POT1", "PARN")
for(i in vec){
  gg <- FeaturePlot(cts.seurat.obj, features = c(i))
  print(gg)
}
dev.off()
graphics.off()
```

I'm also not sure whether you need to set `combine=FALSE` in [FeaturePlot](https://satijalab.org/seurat/reference/featureplot)

As noted by John Polo, you should give quite a bit more detail of what you are doing and a reproducible example.

Comment: you are right. I didnt need onefile=FALSE. Also, print() fixed this issue.